# how to get first and last column of a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix lets say:

```
a =
    401.4800  344.0900  305.0300  462.2100  310.0600  397.3400  502.5900
    547.7100  429.9600  540.3400  737.3600  491.4700  474.7400  735.8700
```

I want to get the first and last columns only so that:

```
b = 
    401.4800  502.5900
    547.7100  735.8700
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
b = a(:,[1,end])
```

This means: all rows (`:`), first and last column (`[1,end]`).